# External power source is turning off

Tags: arduino, arduino-due

My circuit with Arduino Due works perfectly with USB, when I plug a 9V battery on Power Jack works for some seconds then Arduino just turn off.
I tried with 3 new batteries and VIN PIN as well, is my board defective?

Comment: Hard to say, can you measure the voltage across the battery when connected.

A 9V battery is not going to power a Due for very long, you should consider a larger battery or a lower power board.

Comment: The only way you could have the Due work with a 9V battery, would be to keep it in low power/sleep mode as long as possible, optimizing its wake up time to the strict minimum. Obviously, the less it's "awake", the longer it will work.

Answer (score 0):

please check AMS 1117 ic..
first remove all connection and give 9 volt in input of ic.
After check voltage on output pin.
if output voltage is not equle to 3.3V,change ic.
your controller will work properly